# React JS How to disable zoom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zooming, meta, disable

Im building a web app and I want to disable the zoom with 2 fingers. I have tried this

> meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width, initial-scale=1,
> maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"

but is not working.
The app will run on tablets.

Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the React-Helmet you can put your metadata in the render-function of your Component like this:

```
render(){ 
    return <div>
        <Helmet>
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        </Helmet>
        [...]
    </div>
}
```

Look at the [Helmet documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) for further information.

Comment: Typo: meta tag missing closing bracket.

Comment: So does this go on the index.html after doing create react app?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean with "after create react app". You can put the _<Helmet>_-tag directly to your render() function in the component class. So it is after creating the react app and before the build.